# What is "template <typename From, typename Tag> struct Alias;" in c++?

Tags: c++

The following is the code:

```
namespace o
{

template <typename From, typename Tag> struct Alias;
template <typename From, typename Tag>
inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const Alias<From, Tag> &inst);

template <typename From, typename Tag> struct Alias final
{ ...... } 
}
```

I was wondering, what is this `template <typename From, typename Tag> struct Alias`. I know what is the meaning of a template function. Is this a template struct or something like that?

Comment: It is a forward declaration

Comment: *Is this a template struct*, Yep.  It forward declares a struct template.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> was wondering, what is this template  struct Alias. I know what is the meaning of a template function. Is this a template struct or something like that?

That's exactly what it is.

Specifically, that line is a forward declaration, to allow you to use the template struct in a function before you actually define what is in the struct.

The following line(s):

```
<typename From, typename Tag> struct Alias final { ...... }
```

actually defines what's in the template struct.

Template structs work similarly to template functions in the sense that the compiler generates a specific case of the struct when it needs it. Like functions, template structs act as a blueprint for the compiler to generate classes from the blueprint when it needs to.

Comment: A not-related question, what is this  std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const Alias<From, Tag> &inst); I think I can understand this as an inline function with return type std::ostream &, but then I got lost with this operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const Alias<From, Tag> &inst);

Comment: It's a [custom overload of the stream operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes).

Comment: that's what I would guess.